# Deleting odd numbered lines from a text file using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a very large text file that has:

content

meaningless content

content

meaningless content

....

I still want blank lines in between "content", so I just want the "meaningless content" lines to be blank. Ideally, I'd love to have:

content

content

content

with a full blank line between content.

So I want to delete the even numbered lines using MATLAB. I can't use Bash. I had the following code set up:

```
fid = fopen('file.txt');

while ~feof(fid);
fileline=fgets(fid); 

if mod(linenumber,2) == 0
   delete line
end  

end
fclose all;
```

However, I don't really know the syntax for line number and whether or not in principle this code is sound. Any critiques or better ways to do this? I can't use Bash scripts unfortunately.

Comment: Open 2 files at once; one to read and another to write. Read 2 lines at a time, and only write the first line. FYI, modifying a file in place is rather difficult.

Comment: Will this still give me a blank space between the stuff that I want to write?

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways of doing this: either read everything in and extract the data of interest, or read line-by-line and write out the parts you want. Which approach is best depends on the data in question; if it's a small file that can be completely fitted in memory I'd read it en masse, since line-by-line reading is not really efficient.

That being said, here's an implementation that does line-by-line:

```
fid_in = fopen('file.txt');
fid_out = fopen('outfile.txt', 'w+');

while ~feof(fid_in)
    line = fgetl(fid_in);
    fprintf(fid_out, '%s\n\n', line);    %//note the extra new line
    fgetl(fid_in);    %//read and discard next line
end

fclose(fid_in);
fclose(fid_out);
```